# Bitnami LAMP stacks virtual hosts within virtualhost section

Tags: virtualhost, lamp, bitnami

I am trying to set up a virtual host so that my wordpress app on the Bitnami LAMP stack can be hosted on my website, www.iconverge.us. For reference, I am using AWS lightsail as my host. But I am getting this error:

```
bitnami@ip:~/apps/wordpress/conf$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
Unmonitored apache
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:
<VirtualHost> cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section
apache config test fails, aborting

AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:
<VirtualHost> cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section
apache config test fails, aborting
Monitored apache
```

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file, in the directory ~/apps/wordpress/conf/:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.iconverge.us
    ServerAlias iconverge.us *.iconverge.us
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.iconverge.us
    ServerAlias iconverge.us *.iconverge.us
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.key"

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are setting a `<VirtualHost>` label inside another `<VirtualHost>` label. I can't see this situation directly in the `~/apps/wordpress/conf/` you're sharing, but this directive can be a part of included file `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf`, can you take a look if this file contains a `<VirtualHost>` label?

Comment: This does not contain a `<VirtualHost>` label. It instead has a `<Directory>` and also a RewriteEngine On, RewriteRule, etc. However, it includes `htaccess.conf`, which does not have `<VirtualHost>` either

Comment: I am also following this [guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/components/apache/#How_to_create_a_Virtual_Host.3f) on creating virtual hosts exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you didn't include `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`.

If so, remove or comment it out.

**This is how it should be done according to [bitnami docs](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/apache/#how-to-create-a-virtual-host):**

-Comment out the line that includes the prefix configuration file in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` file:

```
  # Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

-Include the virtual host configuration file for WordPress in the `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf` file:

```
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```